# 3 Gang smart switch over 3 Gang USA switch box

Tags: switch, smart-switch, home-automation

I am trying to install 3 Gang smart touch switch in the place of traditional 3 switch
eg: [image]

the issue is, The 3 gang smart switch comes with only 12cm width 7.5cm height. But the socket box in the drywall is 16CM X 12CM.
How to fit this ?

1. Should I replace the gang box?
2. Should I get 3 gang to 2 gang adapter plate?

How to cleanly install the smart switch in this scenario?

[image]

Comment: What country is this in? Based on the top picture (but just a stock picture, not "real") and the box picture (showing typical US-style wire nuts) and references to "gangs", I suspect US. But cm measurements points to elsewhere. In any case, I am **extremely dubious bout the legality of this switch**. For US use it should be approved by UL, ETL or similar, none of which is indicated. In addition, it is marked for 100 - 250V. That is normal for laptop power supplies. It is **not** normal for permanently installed switches.

Comment: Buy a blank 3-gang cover plate and cut a hole in the middle of it large enough for the back side of your smart switch to fit through.

Comment: Why do you want to use this model of switch in particular?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use that apparently non-listed and thus illegal to install switch in a US home, you have two options.

1. Install three of them, or really, three single-pole smart switches. It's what your box is set up for, so it will work just fine. You will likely still need a triple Decora plate. Maybe don't use this brand, since their Amazon reviews include more than a few mentions of very high failure rates.
2. Install a three pole single space switch and use a 'sectional' wall plate to make a wall plate that has two blank spots and one spot for your switch. You'll use two blank sections and one Decora section.

This particular pictured switch won't fit properly at all in the triple box, because there's no way to finish out the cover next to it. It's intended to go in a single-gang box. You also can't swap down to a smaller box because of the number of wires in this box.